# Check if I am heading towards a or away from a point google maps flutter

Tags: flutter, google-maps-flutter, geolocator

I am using `https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire2` to get some places that are within a radius.

```
 var reference = geoFlutterFire
        .collection(collectionRef: firebaseFirestore.collection(path))
        .within(
          center: center,
          radius: 0.2, //in km
          field: field,
          strictMode: true,
        );
```

Once the device is within that radius a notification is created.
My problem is that even if the device walks parallel to a target point but within the radius I get the notification which is fine from the point of view of geoflutterfire2. The package is doing what it is supposed to do.
Now, is there a way to figure out if I am walking towards a point?